# Learn Emacs/Slime the Hard way (from 10 years of Vim)

Tags: vim, emacs, clojure, slime

This is a genuine question, not intended to start a flame war.

I've used Vim for over 10 years; watching people use Emacs/Slime ... has made me decide to learn Emacs/Slime.

I want to get up to speed as fast as quickly:

- there are a bunch of "finger macros" I instinctively do -- I want to figure out the equivalent in Emacs/Slime & retrain myself
- Since I'm familiar with Clojure, writing elisp config won't be a problem (minus the dynamic vars sometimes)

What should I be reading / memorizing?

EDIT: note, I have tried VimClojure, and decided I like Slime/Swank more.

Comment: Use a [vim emulator package](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil). It will make the transition easier and you can keep using the keys you are used to.

Comment: dynamic vars rarely come into it.  Emacs 24 has lexical-binding as well.

Comment: event_jr: I have to disagree with that -- when it comes to writing *config*, I'd say dynamic binding nearly always comes into it. Of course, you can do a great deal without ever worrying about that aspect, but it's always going to be the default (and Emacs wouldn't be remotely so flexible if that ever changed).

Comment: Tom: you should write that as a proper answer (perhaps listing the other options besides Evil as well), because I think that is very likely to be the best approach for someone who is already so used to Vim.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When I learn a new editor (or tool of any kind), the moment I don't know how to do something (e.g. Save a File), I google up the answer, then do it, **3x** over.

In Emacs, save a file is C-x C-s.   Every time you cannot remember what it is, do it three times.  It'll become second nature VERY quickly.

Never "cheat" because you're in a rush, or feeling lazy.   Research each command as you need it, and repeat it until it becomes a "finger macro".

Comment: Also: learn how to remap keys and change unconvenient key bindings as needed. C-x C-s is a too complex key combination for such frequent operation as saving a file. It should be a single key. I bind it to F2.

Comment: @Tom: lol, I've never heard of people binding the F# keys, however, I no longer see a reason to not use them. What do you use F1 -> F12 for?

Comment: @abelenky: this advice (the use it 3x over) is very useful -- I never quite realized how much effort is wasted in "relearning"

Comment: "LOL?" Emacs is about making the editor adapt to you, not the other way around, so it's perfectly all right to change keybindings and even bind F-keys. Lot's of people do it. The default bindings are often horrible. I follow the rule that the more often an operation is invoked the shorter it's key combo must be for efficiency. Buffer switching, for example, is one of the most frequent operations, so it should be on a single key. The default is  C-x C-b, you need to press 4 keys, which is very inefficent. The point is do not accept the default bindings blindly, but change them mercilessly.

Comment: @Tom:  That is one theory.  However, in a team environment where many of us work on co-workers computers quite frequently, the need for CONSISTENT bindings is also very important.  BTW, C-x C-b is 3 keystrokes, you just hold down C- for the sequence.

Comment: It was answer for user1311390, but I also worked in a team environment and still managed to keep my own configuration. 3 keystrokes is still too much for such a frequent operation as buffer switching.

Comment: @Tom mapping F# keys <-- now I understand the statement that Emacs was created by people who played the piano.